# Django nose coverage vs manage.py test gives differing CLI order-dependent results

Tags: python, django, nose, coverage.py, django-nose

I am running simple nose tests on a Django website (code available [here](https://github.com/ChrisFreeman/materials_catalog.git)). Depending on the order that the CLI commands are issued, I get vastly different results!

Looking at many posts, it seems related to when coverage started with respect to the load process. What I don't understand is:

- Why are the missed statements so different between the two methods?
- Why does the coverage go way up if I run one method after the other?

I am focusing on the coverage of `minerals/views.py`

The Django `settings.py` file contains the configuration info:

```
# Use nose to run all tests
TEST_RUNNER = 'django_nose.NoseTestSuiteRunner'

# Nose will measure coverage on the folllowing apps
NOSE_ARGS = [
    '--with-coverage',
    '--cover-package=minerals',
    '--cover-html',
]
```

I am running on Ubuntu 14.04LTS, with Python 3.5.1, using a virtualenv requirements file:

```
coverage==4.1
Django==1.9.6
django-debug-toolbar==1.4
django-nose==1.4.3
nose==1.3.7
sqlparse==0.1.19
```

#### Running test method 1:

When I run the tests using `coverage run --source '.' manage.py test minerals`, then `minerals/views.py` is **missing statements: 12-13, 18-49**.

```
$ coverage run --source '.' manage.py test minerals
nosetests minerals --with-coverage --cover-package=minerals --cover-html --verbosity=1
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
..
Name                                             Stmts   Miss  Cover
--------------------------------------------------------------------
[...]
minerals/views.py                                   18      8    56%
--------------------------------------------------------------------
TOTAL                                               73     48    34%
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.809s
```

Note: Yes, for some unknown reason, the number of missed statements between the run above and the report below changes.

The full coverage `report -m` (from the file `report_source`):

```
Name                                             Stmts   Miss  Cover   Missing
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
manage.py                                            6      0   100%
mineral_catalog/__init__.py                          0      0   100%
mineral_catalog/settings.py                         21      0   100%
mineral_catalog/urls.py                              6      0   100%
mineral_catalog/views.py                             4      1    75%   6
mineral_catalog/wsgi.py                              4      4     0%   10-16
minerals/__init__.py                                 0      0   100%
minerals/admin.py                                    3      0   100%
minerals/apps.py                                     3      3     0%   1-5
minerals/migrations/0001_initial.py                  6      6     0%   3-15
minerals/migrations/0002_auto_20160608_1153.py       5      5     0%   3-14
minerals/migrations/__init__.py                      0      0   100%
minerals/models.py                                  24      1    96%   30
minerals/templatetags/__init__.py                    0      0   100%
minerals/templatetags/mineral_extras.py             12      6    50%   13-16, 22-23
minerals/tests.py                                   20     20     0%   1-31
minerals/urls.py                                     5      0   100%
minerals/views.py                                   18     11    39%   12-13, 18-49
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
TOTAL                                              137     57    58%
```

#### Running test method 2:

If I run the tests using `./manage.py test minerals`, then `minerals/views.py` is **missing statements 1-10, 16, 42**.

```
$ ./manage.py test minerals
nosetests minerals --with-coverage --cover-package=minerals --cover-html --verbosity=1
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
..
Name                                             Stmts   Miss  Cover
--------------------------------------------------------------------
[...]
minerals/views.py                                   18      8    56%
--------------------------------------------------------------------
TOTAL                                               73     48    34%
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.818s
```

The full coverage `report -m` (from the file `report_manage`):

```
Name                                             Stmts   Miss  Cover   Missing
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
minerals/__init__.py                                 0      0   100%
minerals/admin.py                                    3      3     0%   1-6
minerals/apps.py                                     3      3     0%   1-5
minerals/migrations/0001_initial.py                  6      0   100%
minerals/migrations/0002_auto_20160608_1153.py       5      0   100%
minerals/migrations/__init__.py                      0      0   100%
minerals/models.py                                  24     24     0%   1-30
minerals/templatetags/__init__.py                    0      0   100%
minerals/templatetags/mineral_extras.py             12      8    33%   1-10, 19-23
minerals/tests.py                                   20      0   100%
minerals/urls.py                                     5      5     0%   1-10
minerals/views.py                                   18      8    56%   1-10, 16, 42
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
TOTAL                                               96     51    47%
```

#### Running test method 3:

If I remove the `cover/` directory and the `.coverage` file between test runs, Methods 1 and 2 above produce the same results each time as to be expected. However, if I run Method 1, *then* run Method 2 (leaving the `cover/` dir and `.coverage` in place from Method 1), I get much different results. `minerals/views.py` is only **missing statement 42**.

```
$ ./manage.py test minerals
nosetests minerals --with-coverage --cover-package=minerals --cover-html --verbosity=1
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
..
Name                                             Stmts   Miss  Cover
--------------------------------------------------------------------
[...]
minerals/views.py                                   18      1    94%
--------------------------------------------------------------------
TOTAL                                               73      4    95%
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.788s
```

The full coverage `report -m` (from file `report_sourceTHENmanage`):

```
Name                                             Stmts   Miss  Cover   Missing
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
manage.py                                            6      0   100%
mineral_catalog/__init__.py                          0      0   100%
mineral_catalog/settings.py                         21      0   100%
mineral_catalog/urls.py                              6      0   100%
mineral_catalog/views.py                             4      1    75%   6
mineral_catalog/wsgi.py                              4      4     0%   10-16
minerals/__init__.py                                 0      0   100%
minerals/admin.py                                    3      0   100%
minerals/apps.py                                     3      3     0%   1-5
minerals/migrations/0001_initial.py                  6      0   100%
minerals/migrations/0002_auto_20160608_1153.py       5      0   100%
minerals/migrations/__init__.py                      0      0   100%
minerals/models.py                                  24      1    96%   30
minerals/templatetags/__init__.py                    0      0   100%
minerals/templatetags/mineral_extras.py             12      2    83%   22-23
minerals/tests.py                                   20      0   100%
minerals/urls.py                                     5      0   100%
minerals/views.py                                   18      1    94%   42
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
TOTAL                                              137     12    91%
```

I'm not sure how to proceed from this point. I would like to be able to get consistent results using a single CLI comand.

Please let me know if there is more information I need to provide to help debug this!

**Update:**

Experimenting with `py.test`, I was able to get a single line coverage using:

```
$ coverage run --source minerals -m py.test minerals/tests.py 
============================================ test session starts =============================================
platform linux -- Python 3.5.1, pytest-2.9.2, py-1.4.31, pluggy-0.3.1
django settings: mineral_catalog.settings (from ini file)
rootdir: [...]/mineral_catalog, inifile: pytest.ini
plugins: django-2.9.1
collected 2 items 

minerals/tests.py ..    

========================================= 2 passed in 10.88 seconds ==========================================
$ coverage report -m
Name                                             Stmts   Miss  Cover   Missing
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
minerals/__init__.py                                 0      0   100%
minerals/admin.py                                    3      0   100%
minerals/apps.py                                     3      3     0%   1-5
minerals/migrations/0001_initial.py                  6      0   100%
minerals/migrations/0002_auto_20160608_1153.py       5      0   100%
minerals/migrations/__init__.py                      0      0   100%
minerals/models.py                                  24      1    96%   30
minerals/templatetags/__init__.py                    0      0   100%
minerals/templatetags/mineral_extras.py             12      2    83%   22-23
minerals/tests.py                                   20      0   100%
minerals/urls.py                                     5      0   100%
minerals/views.py                                   18      1    94%   42
```

---

```
TOTAL                                               96      7    93%
```